# Run executable in Desktop mode with Django / Python on IIS / Windows

Tags: python, django, iis

**The idea:**

There is a Node.JS server which sends a request to the IIS server which is running Django / Python. It will send two files to the server which need to be converted with a program which needs to be run in the foreground mode.

So I already looked around in pretty much everything related to IIS and the running of executables here on SO, but still haven't got it working.

I got the following code to run the application from Django:

```
subprocess.call("C:\example.exe")
```

There will be probably be some serious security issues (although the server is only reachable from the local network) with the following setup, but here it is:

- I'm running a Django application on IIS.
- I've set the Application Pool Identity to my local user
- I've given "Full Control" permission to "Everyone"

When the subprocess call gets executed it will add the program to my Background Processes with the USER being set to my local user.

**Questions:**

- How do I make the program start in Desktop Mode?
- Should I perhaps add another step (start another service) which will then start the program?

**Edit:**

Could I perhaps make a file watcher which watches if files get stored on the Windows Server and then triggers an executable based on that?

Comment: Do you want a web interface to start a desktop program?

Comment: I want a website to be able to start a desktop program. Be it directly, with a scheduler, through another program, or in a different way. It's a converter which needs to convert files with a program and then send the result back.

Comment: How do you want to handle sessions? What if 2 people request the same application to start at the same time? Can you run the converter in a console?

Comment: There is a node server in front which handles the queue and makes sure only one request is send to the Windows server. I'm unable to run the converter in the console, it really needs to open as a desktop program.